# How to efficiently automate teradata query to fetch last week's data from a database?

Tags: sql, date, automation, teradata

I have scheduled a query in Teradata. It fetches last week's data on a weekly basis. When I used the below condition, I'm getting spool out error.

```
between (current_date-7) and (current_date-1)
```

When I hard code the dates (e.g: between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-07'), there is no such issue. Any help on how this works?

Comment: Is a PPI defined on the table? If so, then are the ranges defined appropriately for `current_date-7` - `current_date-1`

Comment: Is it possible that the data type for the condition is not actually a date and stored as a CHAR() or VARCHAR()?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between a hardcoded date and a calculation based on `current_date`. It's resolved by the parser and in Explain this  condition show as `between date '2015-03-31' and date '201-04-06'`.

If Explain still shows the calculation you run an ancient Teradata version or `DisablePeekUsing` has been modified in dbscontrol due to some unknown reason.

Otherwise you might have more data for this week and now you hit your spot limit.